# li.toUpperCase():not selector difficulties

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code that looks something like this:

```
$('.myList li:not(:contains(' + myWord + '))').css({'color' : red' });
```

When called, this will turn everything that doesn't contain my keyword red.

However, this is not a case insensitive search. To make it so, I've tried something like this:

```
$('.myList li.'+toUpperCase()+':not(:contains(' + myWord.toUpperCase() + '))').css({'color' : 'red' });
```

But that just throws errors.

How can I do a :not(:contains search that is case insensitive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest a simpler approach:

```
$('.myList li').filter(function(){
    // I may have become lost in your approach, but the following
    // will filter the list to those nodes that *do not* contain
    // text equal to that contained in the myWord variable
    var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
    return text.indexOf(myWord.toLowerCase()) == -1;
}).css('color', red);
```

Note that:

```
$('.myList li.'+toUpperCase()+':not(:contains(' + myWord.toUpperCase() + '))').css({'color' : 'red' });
```

You seem to be searching for a list item with a class-name equal to the `upperCase()` function (which won't happen), and then you're looking to force the `:contains()` selector to be case-insensitive, which you've already found it isn't.

Comment: Oh, it was *meant* to be case-insensitive..?

Comment: Although OP states "this is not a case insensitive search", his `toUpperCase` attemp suggests otherwise. To me, code speaks better than paragraphs

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you do it with `filter` instead, it's more concise:

```
$('.myList li').filter(function() {
  return !new RegExp(myWord, 'i').test($(this).text());
}).css('color', 'red');
```

You can remove the `i` flag if you want it to be case-sensitive.